# Intent bitmap return in Non Activity class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am developing an app and I need it to be capable of using the camera - take a photo and return the image in a Bitmap.

- the app is programmed in cocos2d-android (no longer maintained, I am aware of that, but I think this should work regardless. At least I hope)
- the code snippet below is in a class that extends CCLayer(a cocos2d element) so I can't use onActivityForResult()

I have this in a non activity class that generates a tile puzzle based on a bitmap

```
    appcontext = MainActivity.context;
    intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this is required to call "Intent()" in a non-activity class.
    appcontext.startActivity(intent);;
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Bitmap mybit = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

The camera starts normally but after the selection is made I am brought to the initial screen that launches the camera.

I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you get when you debug. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I am brought to the initial screen that launches the camera". "It is extremely urgent" -- then you need to urgently explain better what your symptoms are.

Comment: `Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();` won't do anything. `startActivity` does not do that. However, I presume `MainActivity.context` is actually an activity, hence you could use `startActivityForResult` and receive the bitmap in `onActivityResult in MainActivity`.

Comment: Extremely sorry for the poor explanation. I have edited the post. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't use onActivityForResult()

You do not have a choice. If you want to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you will need to override `onActivityResult()` and process the selected bitmap there.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // this is required to call "Intent()" in a non-activity class.
```

It is required to call `startActivity()` from a non-`Activity` `Context`. Since you need to use `startActivityForResult()` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you will need an `Activity`.

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
Bitmap mybit = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

You seem to think that `startActivity()` is a blocking call. It is not. The statements shown above will be executed immediately. As a result, you will not have a bitmap to work with here. You need to use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: I understand.  Is there any other way of launching the camera and returning a bitmap without intents?

Comment: @user244637: Only by working with the camera hardware yourself. That's not especially easy, and I have no idea how [my library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) will work in a `cocos2d-android` environment. You will still need an activity, though, as the camera preview has to go somewhere.

Comment: in this environment everything runs within a MainActivity. Think this will work?

Comment: @user244637: It *could* work. I know little about cocos2d and therefore have no idea of whether it will cause problems or not.